# Seaborn x axis doesn't cover all the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

When I make a Seaborn boxplot using the tips data set per the example on the [Seaborn website](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) the x axis covers the length of the boxplot.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("ticks")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
```

[image: Seaborn boxplot]

But if I change the data set and do the same thing the x axis doesn't even cover the upper quartile. Why does the default not extend to cover all the data and how can I fix this? I would like it to go from below the lowest data point to above the highest data point.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'total_bill' : [3082, 2024, 3333, 1544, 1861]})
sns.set_style("ticks")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x=my_df["total_bill"])
sns.despine(trim=True)
```

[image: boxplot two]

Comment: I have had similar issues with the seaborn examples. Have you looked into the shape/ data in `tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")` ? What does it look like, is it fairly consistent with what you're giving as input?

Comment: I modelled `my_df` off of tips, so it is the same. I don't think the axis is that example is very good though either. There is a total bill value that is 50.81, which extends beyond the axis. I want the axis to cover every point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitely asking seaborn to cut the x axis by putting `sns.despine(trim=True)` in your code. You may leave that out to obtain the full axis

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'total_bill' : [3082, 2024, 3333, 1544, 1861]})
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x=my_df["total_bill"])

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you then want to get rid of the spines, you can still add

```
sns.despine(left=True)
```

[image]

You may manually set the tick positions according to your liking. In the simplest case you use the already present tick positions, and fix them to the axis

```
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
```

[image]